# Can't resolve NZEC error in Python on codechef, Although it gave correct output on IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

```
def gcd(x,y):
    while(x!=y):
        if(y != 0):
            return(gcd(y,x%y))
        else:
            return(x)
t = input()
while (t>0):
    t = t-1
    a,b,n = raw_input().split(" ")
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    n=int(n)
    x = pow(a,n) + pow(b,n)
    y = a-b
    print(gcd(x,y))
```

Here i got NZEC(Runtime) error in codechef but if i write test cases mannually then it is work finely, So please Help...

Comment: You tagged python-3.x yet you are using `raw_input()` which is python 2 only.  Maybe you have both installed and code chef and the IDE are running different versions of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python 3

1. Convert the `t` variable to `int`

   ```
   t=int(t)
   ```
2. Change `raw_input()` to `input()`.

Comment the line if you have not.